# How to combine or and and in the if statement vba in with do until

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Is it possible to combine `Do Until` with `If` statement containing `Or` and `And`?

This is not working correctly, it doesn't take `AND` condition into consideration, it runs but like `AND` wouldn't be there

```
i = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
    If Cells(i, 13) = "Role Adjustment" Or Cells(i, 13) = "New Role" _
            And Cells(i, 15) = "FALSE" Then
        Cells(i, 15).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 49407
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

And when I try it to do with `And` and `Or` combination with brackets, it's not working at all

```
i = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
    If (Cells(i, 13) = "Role Adjustment" Or Cells(i, 13) = "New Role") _
            And Cells(i, 15) = "FALSE" Then
        Cells(i, 15).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 49407
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Is there any possibility how to combine it?
What I am trying to achieve is, when one cell is containing `"Role Adjustment"` or `"New Role"` and other cell is containing `"FALSE"`, to change the color of the cell.

Comment: When you say 'its not working at all', do you mean, it doesn't find any cells which match your criteria? Are you sure your data is set up in such a way that in at least one instance, it matches the criteria? With the brackets seems to me like it should work. Possible reason - you have the AND criteria listed as "FALSE" - but thats text value, different different from the boolean FALSE [with no brackets].

Comment: This is also easily obtainable with Conditional Formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option should work, and @Grade'Eh'Bacon is probably correct:

Change this:

```
If Cells(i, 13) = "Role Adjustment" Or Cells(i, 13) = "New Role" _
        And Cells(i, 15) = "FALSE" Then
```

---

to this:

```
If (UCase(Cells(i, 13).Value2) = "ROLE ADJUSTMENT" _
    Or _
    UCase(Cells(i, 13).Value2) = "NEW ROLE") _
    And _
    Cells(i, 15).Value2 = False Then
```

or

```
If (UCase(Cells(i, 13).Value2) = "ROLE ADJUSTMENT" _
    Or _
    UCase(Cells(i, 13).Value2) = "NEW ROLE") _
    And _
    UCase(Cells(i, 15).Text) = "FALSE" Then
```

---

Test code:

```
Sub testLogicalOps()
    Dim y As Range
    For Each y In Range("B1:B10")
        Debug.Print IIf((y = 5 Or y = 3) And y.Offset(0, 1) = False, "Yes", "No")
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a simple case of realizing how excel reads the IF statement. It is evaluating the `Or` statement first and going True and never looking at the `And` It can get a little ugly but you have to use the `And` first and then `Or` it. Try this

```
If Cells(i, 13) = "Role Adjustment" And Cells(i, 15) = "FALSE" Or Cells(i, 13) = "New Role" And Cells(i, 15) = "FALSE" Then
```

This evaluates the And condition first and if False then looks at the Or.

Conditional Formatting way.

```
=AND($O1="FALSE", OR($M1="Role Adjustment", $M1="New Role"))
```

Comment: While your ordering may be correct, the OP's use of brackets should resolve his ordering to work the way s/he wants - there is something else going on in his/her data.

Comment: Possibly but that is not for me to determine since I cannot see the data.